# "str_getcsv" convert chinese has failed result

Tags: php, laravel

**When I use PHP8, the error is not found.**

**And If you must use PHP7, look there: [str_getcsv parses the CSV error](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78457), and suggest use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Chinese_China.65001');`**

If you need more infomation, read please, and look "More test" part.

Thanks @jspit and @Álvaro-gonzález help.

---

everybody, I use Laravel 6 and writing feature test.

When `str_getcsv` running to chinese, the function return failed result.

You can use `str_getcsv("\"未定义\",\"良品\",\"二手\",\"瑕疵\",\"良品无吊牌\"")` to test it error.

In my computer, `var_dump` the result:

```bash
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "未定义"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "良品",二手""
  [2]=>
  string(24) "瑕疵",良品无吊牌""
}
```

You can find `良品, 二手` is signle string.

I find StackOverflow and [Github Issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29617).

And defined `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'zh_CN.UTF-8');` or `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'zh_CN.UTF8');` in `index.php`.

API request is right, But in **PHPUnit feature test**, not working yet.

Laravel [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8a02e8fc5ad22e47cc0ebec075d6ff7edf0e7b8c/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationRuleParser.php#L275-L285) about this question.

thanks.

---

More test:

**Right result**:

PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2022 23:10:34) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64), Zend Engine v4.1.8

PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2022 08:28:43) (NTS), Zend Engine v4.1.8

PHP 8.0.20 (cli) (built: Jun  8 2022 09:10:24) ( NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 ), Zend Engine v4.0.20

PHP 7.2.33 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2020 22:53:01) ( NTS ), Zend Engine v3.2.0, with Zend OPcache v7.2.33

**Wrong result**:

PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2020 10:24:14) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 ), Zend Engine v3.2.0

PHP 7.4.30 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 15:36:03) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 ), Zend Engine v3.4.0

Comment: `var_dump()` output suggests you have valid UTF-8 (at least byte counts match). Does `setlocale()` succeed when you run PHPUnit tests?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález in test, try `var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'zh_CN.UTF8'))` is false, and try in api requets will `false` return -- but working in request. I find document show: *or false if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform*, What happen? I use windows10 / chinese languge / git-bash terminal.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for you help. now I will leave my workspace, and back to home. if you has suggestion, please tell me.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://3v4l.org/vaSkl

Comment: @jspit WTH, I try in NTS version PHP is right woking, I will testing more example, and reply.

Comment: What......I try 8.1.10 ZTS & NTS is working....maybe is my workspace php version error, I will try again at work time.